# Comparing two audio files stress, rhythm and intonation

Tags: java, audio

I want to compare the stress, rhythm and intonation of two audio files in java. For example, get the audio files of two speakers and compare the second speaker's rhythm relative to the first speaker. Not the similarity of the audio files.